# PHP function/class that formats/indents my HTML code?

Tags: php, html

Is there a PHP function/class that cleans my HTML code?

For example:

```
$html = "<ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li>";
echo htmlClean($html);

/*
    Outputs:
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
    </ul>
*/
```

Comment: I mean formatting the HTML source code. So it becomes more readable when looking at the source code. Like in the example.

Comment: dependent on your input in think, to use '\n' etc..

Comment: unformatted: <div><p>Hello World</p></div>, then the function returns the given html with line breaks and tabbed spaces according to element depth... i'm afraid i'm not using the right term...

Answer (score 3):

[tidy](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/class.tidy.php). or one of the third party php libraries

Answer (score 2):

This might help: [Indent HTML Code](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1964)

Comment: @DemoUser your link is broken

Answer (score 0):

keep html out of your php for a start, you should only echo out strings not blocks of html.

```
<ul>
      <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
        <li><?php echo $item['one']; ?></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

If needs must you could try clean the code up with " Heredoc string quoting "

```
echo <<<EOF
<ul>
<li>"$item1"</li>
<li>"$item2"</li>
</ul>
EOF;
```

Comment: In this case is hard to keep HTML from PHP, I have a function that returns an HTML UL list based on the categories stored on MySQL. In this case, php does all the hard work of making the list, I just have to pass the table name where the categories names are stored.

Comment: Your output does not suggest this...may we seen the full code.  Im sure we can give you a better suggestion if we see what your trying to achieve mate.